# Does camel log influence on body content?

Tags: apache-camel

At some point during debugging the info coming through the system I was forced to watch the data in XML format entering the system. To do that I added additional line for logging the XML content, and the XML content appears in logs.

At this point the system started to generate problems with marshaling the XML content to the XML Object.

`org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettyChannelBufferStreamCache to the required type: com.company.product.customer.generated.XML with value org.apache.camel.`

I thought that some new problem occurred in the system, and even didn't think that introducing the log field can cause some troubles. Finally after many hours of fighting I decided to remove the log line and it started to work seamless again.

Does the log tag has any influence on body message? Why it might happen?

```
<post uri="/requestXml"
    type="com.company.product.customer.generated.XML"
    outType="java.lang.String">
    <description>Request</description>

    <route>
        <to uri="bean:authenticationService?method=checkUser"/> 
        <!--log loggingLevel="INFO" message="Incomming XML ${body}"/-->
        <to uri="bean:messageTranslator?method=XMLRequestToConfiguration"/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is related to the fact that you can read streams only once.

> While stream types (like StreamSource, InputStream and Reader) are
>   commonly used in messaging for performance reasons, they also have an
>   important drawback: they can only be read once. In order to be able to
>   work with message content multiple times, the stream needs to be
>   cached.

You have to enable stream caching in context level like this:

```
<camelContext streamCache="true">
```

There are more options available(e.g enable it in route level). See all available options here.
http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html

Comment: Good one. Can be the solution. +1

Comment: Ok, so I was not so far from the solution, because at some point I added streamCache but I set it to false and later on I removed it. :(